# Ember.js set initial value of property

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to set a default value of a property, depending on another property of the model being loaded.

How do I trigger the setOthers method, after the model has loaded? The **totalPoints** property can change afterwards, and the user should also be able to change the **others** value, from the initial value set in the **setOthers** method.

I have this User model:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend(
  # [ ... ]
  competenceRatings: DS.attr('competenceRatings')
)
```

Here's the controller:

```
App.UsersEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(
  others: 0 # Set others to remaining points, if points > 0 and less than 100.

  totalPoints: (->
    totalPoints = @get('others')
    totalPoints += competenceRating.get('points') for competenceRating in @get('competenceRatings')
    totalPoints
  ).property('competenceRatings.@each.points', 'others')

  setOthers: ->
    totalPoints = @get('totalPoints')
    if totalPoints > 0 and totalPoints < 100
      @set('others', 100 - totalPoints)
)
```

I already tried http://emberjs.com/api/#method_computed_defaultTo:

```
App.UsersEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(
  others: Ember.computed.defaultTo('setOthers') # Set others to remaining points, if points > 0 and less than 100.

  totalPoints: (->
    totalPoints = @get('others')
    totalPoints += competenceRating.get('points') for competenceRating in @get('competenceRatings')
    totalPoints
  ).property('competenceRatings.@each.points', 'others')

  setOthers: (->
    console.log @get('isLoaded')
    value = 0
    totalPoints = @get('totalPoints')
    if totalPoints > 0 and totalPoints < 100
      #@set('others', 100 - totalPoints)
      value = 100 - totalPoints
    value
  ).property()
)
```

Here's the output:

```
true employeenet.js:105386
true employeenet.js:105386
[ ... repeated many, many... many times ... ]
true employeenet.js:105386
<error> VM1936:1
<error> VM1936:1
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded employeenet.js:1
Error: Assertion Failed: Emptying a view in the inBuffer state is not allowed and should not happen under normal circumstances. Most likely there is a bug in your application. This may be due to excessive property change notifications.
    at new Error (native)
    at Error.Ember.Error (http://localhost:3000/assets/employeenet.js:47844:19)
    at Object.Ember.assert (http://localhost:3000/assets/employeenet.js:47073:11)
    at Object.Ember.merge.empty (http://localhost:3000/assets/employeenet.js:71691:11)
    at Ember.CollectionView.Ember.ContainerView.extend.arrayWillChange (http://localhost:3000/assets/employeenet.js:72618:25)
    at Object.sendEvent (http://localhost:3000/assets/employeenet.js:49537:14)
    at Ember.Array.Ember.Mixin.create.arrayContentWillChange (http://localhost:3000/assets/employeenet.js:62031:11)
    at Ember.ArrayProxy.Ember.Object.extend.arrangedContentArrayWillChange (http://localhost:3000/assets/employeenet.js:66416:10)
    at null._arrangedContentWillChange (http://localhost:3000/assets/employeenet.js:66266:10)
    at sendEvent (http://localhost:3000/assets/employeenet.js:49537:14) employeenet.js:50461
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Error: Assertion Failed: Emptying a view in the inBuffer state is not allowed and should not happen under normal circumstances. Most likely there is a bug in your application. This may be due to excessive property ...<omitted>...s. employeenet.js:47073
Error: Assertion Failed: Emptying a view in the inBuffer state is not allowed and should not happen under normal circumstances. Most likely there is a bug in your application. This may be due to excessive property change notifications.
    at new Error (native)
    at Error.Ember.Error (http://localhost:3000/assets/employeenet.js:47844:19)
    at Object.Ember.assert (http://localhost:3000/assets/employeenet.js:47073:11)
    at Object.Ember.merge.empty (http://localhost:3000/assets/employeenet.js:71691:11)
    at Ember.CollectionView.Ember.ContainerView.extend.arrayWillChange (http://localhost:3000/assets/employeenet.js:72618:25)
    at Object.sendEvent (http://localhost:3000/assets/employeenet.js:49537:14)
    at Ember.Array.Ember.Mixin.create.arrayContentWillChange (http://localhost:3000/assets/employeenet.js:62031:11)
    at Ember.ArrayProxy.Ember.Object.extend.arrangedContentArrayWillChange (http://localhost:3000/assets/employeenet.js:66416:10)
    at null._arrangedContentWillChange (http://localhost:3000/assets/employeenet.js:66266:10)
    at sendEvent (http://localhost:3000/assets/employeenet.js:49537:14) employeenet.js:50461
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Error: Assertion Failed: Emptying a view in the inBuffer state is not allowed and should not happen under normal circumstances. Most likely there is a bug in your application. This may be due to excessive property ...<omitted>...s. employeenet.js:47073
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [`Ember.computed.defaultTo`](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_computed_defaultTo).

Something like this should work:

```
App.UsersEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(
  others: Ember.computed.defaultTo('othersDefault')

  totalPoints: (->
    totalPoints = @get('others')
    totalPoints += competenceRating.get('points') for competenceRating in @get('competenceRatings')
    totalPoints
  ).property('competenceRatings.@each.points', 'others')

  othersDefault: (->
    totalPoints = @get('totalPoints')
    if totalPoints > 0 and totalPoints < 100
      @set('others', 100 - totalPoints)
  ).property()
```

Comment: I already did try that. I've updated the question with the results, but thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Can you put up a jsfiddle? There's obviously a recursive loop created somewhere.

Comment: After looking at it again with fresh eyes, I can see that the code is calling 'others' from within totalPoints. That's why I get the recursive loop. Thanks!